# Variable value reset to default when new user iteration starts in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-3.2

i am using JMeter BeanShell Preprocessor to generate unique date value in each iteration. I am using two (2) users for my load test on database . for user 1 the date value generating as expected but when the user change to 2 then date variable value reset to default. what should i do to prevent the reset of date variable value as on insertion i am facing violation of unique key constraint error.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2iJr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euEc9.png)

i have mentioned in the screen shot what I tried . I need help to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

1. [Don't post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)
2. Don't use Beanshell, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

Your problem is that both users are adding 1 day to the date and if the database is configured that way it doesn't allow the same dates - the insert or update will fail.

I don't know the details of your test scenario but you could consider adding current iteration number and/or current virtual user number to the date from the User Defined Variables, the relevant functions are:

- [`vars.getIteration()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getIteration()) - for the iteration number
- [`ctx.getThreadNum()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getThreadNum()) - for the user number

However the best option would be pre-generating the list of dates somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter)

Example Groovy code:

```
def now = new Date()

1.upto(200000,{index ->
    def date = now.plus(index)
    new File('dates.csv') << date.format('yyyy-MM-dd') << System.getProperty('line.separator')
})
```

And then use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to read the generated dates from the `dates.csv` file in your main Thread Group

Given you have 2 users and 100k iterations which means that the last date would be `2570-08-11` so make sure it matches your requirements and the database is capable of accepting the date such far in the future